# inkscape shell mode

Tags: svg, shellexecute, inkscape

I tried to run inkscape shell mode by writing these lines in a .bat file:

inkscape --shell 
 >2.svg -e 2.png 
But it doesn't work at all (no png  files), more over I tried to open the current svg input and I found it damaged and I failed to open it at all.
 Could any one please tell me the right command lines to enter the SHELL mode and execute other inkscape command lines.

Comment: Is your svg file broken? (http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: You might have copied the "> 2.svg" line from an example. I think the ">" shows up if you just type the command "inkscape --shell".

Answer (score 4):

You're redirecting output, using the `>`, to 2.svg. `>` means redirect output to this file.

Probably more correct would be:

```
rem echo the commands you want to execute to a file
echo 2.svg -e 2.png > commands.txt
echo quit >> commands.txt
inkscape --shell < commands.txt
```

not sure if this works because I don't use windows.

Comment: HI,Finally I could work with shell mode, Just by downloading the last version of inkscape, THANKS you ALL.

Comment: This option is really limited, many `verbs` are not supported and require a GUI. So totally contra-productive with the goal of `--shell`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reworked example that was previously exports using flags like so:

```
$ inkscape src/cursors.svg \
  -i wait-22 -w 24 -h 24 -o build/x75/wait-22.png \
  -i progress-22 -w 24 -h 24 -o build/x75/progress-22.png
```

Now done using Bash and Inkscape's actions in its `--shell` mode.
Edited excerpt from Plasma's Breeze cursor build script:

```bash
RAWSVG="src/cursors.svg"
SCALES="50 75 100 125 150 175 200 225 250 275 300"
genPixmaps="file-open:${RAWSVG};"
for CUR in src/config/*.cursor; do
    BASENAME=${CUR##*/}
    BASENAME=${BASENAME%.*}

    for scale in $SCALES; do
        DIR="build/x${scale}"
        # Check if the final PNG already exists, in which case skip generating it 
        if [[ "${DIR}/${BASENAME}.png" -ot ${RAWSVG} ]]; then
            genPixmaps="${genPixmaps} export-id:${BASENAME}; export-width:$((32*scale/100)); export-height:$((32*scale/100)); export-filename:${DIR}/${BASENAME}.png; export-do;"
        fi
    done
done
# Push the entire genPixmaps var as a file to inkscape --shell
inkscape --shell < <(echo "${genPixmaps}")
```

This ends up generating this efficient one-line mess:

```php
file-open:src/cursors.svg; export-id:alias; export-width:16; export-height:16; export-filename:build/x50/alias.png; export-do;export-id:alias; export-width:24; export-height:24; export-filename:build/x75/alias.png; ...
```

See `inkscape --action-list` to get a list of possible actions.

Answer (score -3):

**Exporting SVG to different formats**

- export to bitmap (png)

  `inkscape -f FILENAME.svg -e FILENAME.png`

  loads FILENAME.svg and exports it to FILENAME.png

  `inkscape -f FILENAME.svg -w WIDTH -h HEIGHT -e FILENAME.png`

  loads FILENAME.svg and exports it to FILENAME.png with width size, WIDTH, and height size, HEIGHT, in pixels
- export to pdf

  `inkscape -f FILENAME.svg -A FILENAME.pdf`

  loads FILENAME.svg and exports it to FILENAME.pdf
- export to ps

  `inkscape -f FILENAME.svg -P FILENAME.ps`

  loads FILENAME.svg and exports it to FILENAME.ps
- export to eps

  `inkscape -f FILENAME.svg -E FILENAME.eps`

  loads FILENAME.svg and exports it to FILENAME.eps

**External links:**

- [Inkscape: Guide to a Vector Drawing Program](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/index.html) (online book)

  - [Chapter 25. Using the Command Line](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine.html)

Comment: This is not related to the shell mode